# std::cin is not working properly

Tags: c++, get, cin

I know this question has been asked before, but nothing helped.

I have a program

```
void printInstructions(){
    cout << "\n******INSTRUCTIONS******\n"
         // a lot of text
         << "Press any key to begin...\t";

    /*cin.sync();
     *cin.get()
     *cin.ignore(1);
     *cout << flush;
     */

    string temp;
    cin >> temp;
    cout << '\n';

}

int main()
{

    cout << "***********************\n"
         << "******* WELCOME *******\n"
         << "***********************\n"
         << endl;

    //some stuff

    printInstructions();

   //some other stuff

}
```

I commented all the solutions i tried and only the one with the `temp` works, but with that being clumsy I'm interested why the `cin.get()` or `cin.ignore()` don't work. And yes, I tried std::flush, but it just skipped the `cin.` call and went onward with the program

Comment: The easy fix is to change "Press any key to begin" to "Press the Enter key to begin".

Comment: @FredLarson What would that change? If i use anything else then a given solution it just skips to the rest of the code

Comment: I'm not following you. What you have looks like it should work, but it won't respond to ANY key. The input is buffered, so you won't get the result of the `cin >> temp` until the user hits the Enter key.

Comment: Actually, `getline` works a whole lot better than `cin >> temp`.

Comment: `cin >> noskipws >> temp;` also works.

Comment: Found the answer here http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/75206-cin-not-allowing-input-after-first-use-function.html